# A standard name for an “inversely (uniformly) continuous” map

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, terminology, uniform-continuity

Is there a standard name for a map $f: X → Y$ between metric spaces such that for every $ε > 0$ there is $δ > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < δ$ if $d(f(x), f(y)) < ε$ for $x, y ∈ X$ and/or for a map between topological spaces such that $x ∈ \overline{A}$ if $f(x) ∈ \overline{f[A]}$ for $x ∈ X$, $A ⊆ X$?

This correspond to (uniform) continuity of the inverse with the catch that there may be no proper inverse – the maps are one-to-one but not necessarily onto. If they were also (uniformly) continuous, the proper name would be “embedding”.

Comment: The closure property just says that $f$ is closed and continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There is just “if”, not “iff”. Also it says nothing about points outside of $f[X]$ so the image does not have to be closed. But yes, it says that $f$ is closed or evquivalenty open as a map $X → f[X]$.

Comment: I meant to say that $f: X \to Y$ is closed and continuous iff $\overline{f[A]} = f[\overline{A}]$ for all $A \subseteq X$.